# Crear un select con jquery recibiendo array desde ajax

Tags: html, jquery, json

necesito crear dinámicamente un input para listar todos los municipios de un determinado estado de México, tengo mi consulta correctamente y desde php estoy regresando el array de la siguiente manera.

```
    $idestado = (int)$_POST['idestado'];
    $municipios = new municipiosController();
    $listmunicipios = $municipios->getMunicipioEstado($idestado);
    echo json_encode($listmunicipios);
```

Desde ajax recibo este array y estoy haciendo un foreach para comprobar la información recibida y se supone que "según" la información de la consola todo está bien aunque noto que el array tiene información duplicada no entiendo por que, comparto captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        url:"views/ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:datos,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(regreso){
            Object.keys( regreso ).forEach(function( key ) {
                console.log('key name: ', key);
                console.log('value: ', regreso[key]);
            });
        }
    });
```

La pregunta es: 
De ese array que recibo necesito generar en html las opciones e insertarlas en el select.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <label>Municipio:</label>
     <select class="selectpicker" id="selecmunicipio" name="selecmunicipio" data-live-search="true" title="Selecciona tu municipio" required>

    </select>

</div>
```

El HTML que necesito generar es algo así:

```
<option  value="123">Nombre de la localidad1</option>
```

Para quedar finalmente algo así:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <label>Municipio:</label>
     <select class="selectpicker" id="selecmunicipio" name="selecmunicipio" data-live-search="true" title="Selecciona tu municipio" required>
        <option  value="123">Nombre de la localidad1</option>
        <option  value="13423">Nombre de la localidad2</option> 
        <option  value="123223">Nombre de la localidad3</option>                
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Puedes poner algo así en el `success` de Ajax: **`success: function(regreso){
$.each(regreso, function(k, v) {$('#selecmunicipio').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');});});`**. Para los datos duplicados, tendrás que ver lo que está devolviendo tu petición en PHP.

Comment: He cambiado mi php a esto:

Comment: He cambiado mi php a esto: var_dump($listmunicipios); que es la variable que obtiene el fetchAll de la consulta. En el js estoy imprimiendo lo que recibe  y tengo este resultado. https://image.prntscr.com/image/hRr8yd9hQN6dMhwvAMu9cA.png  empiezo a crear que es mi foreach el que estaba mal, probaré lo que me dices y te comento.

Comment: Desafortunadamente me fue mal :( https://image.prntscr.com/image/H1hh74JCRSeGsH_o5Q-DgQ.png    https://image.prntscr.com/image/rH0EDzzZR6usUMV78dV0RQ.png

Comment: Por lo que se ve en la imagen el `fetchAll` te está devolviendo un array JSON, no un objeto JSON, por lo tanto, deberás acceder a la clave `0` de array para poder leerlo: `$.each(regreso[0], function(k,v)...` todo lo demás lo dejas igual, como en el comentario de más arriba.

Comment: Listo gracias! Lo he resuelto!  :) muy amable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberias iterar los datos seleccionar segun el criterio y luego hacer un append al combo te doy un ejemplo :
donde list es el conjunto de datos.

```
var combo = $('cboMicombo');
    $.each(list, function (obj, item) {    
    if(item.ciudadID== 3) {
            combo.append('<option value="' + item.Id + '">' + item.nombre + '</option>');
    }});
```

para ver la duplicidad de los datos deberias mostrar el codigo del lado servidor asi poder ayudarte con eso.

Comment: He cambiado mi php a esto: var_dump($listmunicipios); que es la variable que obtiene el fetchAll de la consulta. En el js estoy imprimiendo lo que recibe y tengo este resultado. image.prntscr.com/image/hRr8yd9hQN6dMhwvAMu9cA.png empiezo a creer que es mi foreach el que estaba mal.

Comment: Aún así, utilizo tu código pero me marca un error: https://image.prntscr.com/image/16SS1b0WQN2zOn626aVslA.png

Comment: reemplaza list por tu variable que aparentemente es "regreso".

Comment: Daniel, gracias por tu respuesta, verás, he realizado el cambio que me dices y al parecer el asunto se resolvió, solo una duda adicional. Al abrir el select desde el sitio aparece vacío, pero viendo el código me doy cuenta que las opciones si están actualizadas. ¿Tengo que refrescar el combo o algo asi? :(  te comparto una captura.  https://image.prntscr.com/image/TMilxdENS2_bihgq5g7cuw.png

Comment: prueba hacer la carga de datos luego de finalizada la carga de la pagina, generalmente la llamada a la funcion deberia ir:$(document).ready( function () {
  tuFuncion();
});

Comment: Listo muchas gracias ya lo logré! Muy amable por la ayuda :)

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si la misma responde a tu problema. Gracias.