# Como cargar datos sql en un option value aspnet?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

estoy intentando cargar datos de un procedemiento almacenado a un option value, pero la verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo, eh investigado y no encuentro solucion

```
public List<Barra3> RetornarGraficos1()
 {
     List<Barra3> objLista = new List<Barra3>();

     //Data Source=;Initial Catalog= ; User ID= ; Password=
     using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=LID_RIESG_COMERC; Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         string query = "ProductividadM";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         oconexion.Open();

         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 objLista.Add(new Barra3()
                 {
                     Fecha = dr["Fecha"].ToString(),
                     Centro = decimal.Parse(dr["Centro"].ToString()),
                     Occidente = decimal.Parse(dr["Occidente"].ToString()),
                     Oriente = decimal.Parse(dr["Oriente"].ToString()),
                 });
             }
         }
     }

     return objLista;
 }
```

Mi clase

```
public class Barra3
{
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public decimal Centro { get; set; }
    public decimal Occidente { get; set; }
    public decimal Oriente { get; set; }
}
```

el controlador

```
[HttpGet]
 public JsonResult ReporteGraficos1()
 {
     DT_Reporte objDT_Reporte = new DT_Reporte();

     List<Barra3> objLista = objDT_Reporte.RetornarGraficos1();

     return Json(objLista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

en mi vista quisiera cargar datos "fecha" del SP, en estos momentos uso de forma manual, pero no es la solucion que busco, no se haya alguna forma de hacer lo que busco

```
<select id="FechasID">
            <option value="01/06/23">01/06/23</option>
            <option value="15/07/23">15/07/23</option>
            <option value="12/08/23">12/08/23</option>
            <option value="23/09/23" selected>23/09/23</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para realizar esto, existen varias formas de realizarlo, te mostrare un ejemplo sencillo de como realizarlo, para esto vas a requerir usar ViewBag, y un componente de razor en tu vista.

Controlador:

```
        public ActionResult Crear() {

        //ObtenerEstados devuelve un List, en vez de este metodo debes retornar un listado con tu clase Barra3
        ViewBag.estado = estado.ObtenerEstados();

        return View();
    }
```

Luego de esto, pasamos a la vista, en ella es necesario que especifiques un modelo a recibir dentro de ella de esta forma al inicio de la vista:

```
@model KN_WEB.ViewClass.TiqueteEditView
```

Donde veas "KN_WEB.ViewClass.TiqueteEditView" debes reemplazarlo por la ruta donde tengas tu clase de Barra3

Por ultimo, solo crear un DropDownList en tu vista de esta forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x."Key", new SelectList(ViewBag.estado, "Key", "Value"), new { @id = "estado", @class = "form-select" })
```

En este componente de razor debes de modificar los campos "Key" y "Value" por los valores correspondientes que deseas obtener y deplegar dentro del sistema.

Repito, esto solo es una forma de hacerlo, sin embargo existen muchas.

Te dejo por aca algunos links de documentacion donde podras ver varias formas:

- [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44739/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-un-dropdownlist#:~:text=Puedes%20usar%20este%20m%C3%A9todo%20para%20cargar%20DropDownList%3A%20ViewModel%3A,public%20IEnumerable%3CSelectListItem%3E%20Labs%20%7B%20get%3B%20set%3B%20%7D%20%7D](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44739/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-un-dropdownlist#:%7E:text=Puedes%20usar%20este%20m%C3%A9todo%20para%20cargar%20DropDownList%3A%20ViewModel%3A,public%20IEnumerable%3CSelectListItem%3E%20Labs%20%7B%20get%3B%20set%3B%20%7D%20%7D)
- [Crear un select con jquery recibiendo array desde ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129994/crear-un-select-con-jquery-recibiendo-array-desde-ajax)

Espero te haya sido de ayuda.

Saludos.